# Infer multivalent features with tfdv from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-data-validation

I want to infer a schema with tensorflow data validation (tfdv) based on a pandas dataframe of the training data. The dataframe contains a column with a multivalent feature, where multiple values (or None) of the feature can be present at the same time.

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'feat_1': 13, 'feat_2': 'AA, BB', 'feat_3': 'X'},
                   {'feat_1': 7, 'feat_2': 'AA', 'feat_3': 'Y'},
                   {'feat_1': 7, 'feat_2': None, 'feat_3': None}])
```

inferring and displaying the schema results in:

[image]

Thus, tfdv treats the 'feat_2' values as a single string instead of splitting them at the ',' to produce a domain of 'AA', 'BB':

[image]

If if save the values of feature as e.g., `['AA', 'BB']`, the schema inference throws an error:

`ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'list' object", 'Conversion failed for column feat_2 with type object')`

Is there any way to achieve this with tfdv?

Answer (score 2):

A `String` will be interpreted as a `String`. Regarding your issue with the `List`, it might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/90#issuecomment-541966795):

> Currently only pandas columns of primitive types are supported.

Could not find anything more recent. Here is a workaround:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv

df = pd.DataFrame([{'feat_1': 13, 'feat_2': 'AA, BB', 'feat_3': 'X'},
                   {'feat_1': 7, 'feat_2': 'AA', 'feat_3': 'Y'},
                   {'feat_1': 7, 'feat_2': None, 'feat_3': None}])

df['feat_2'] = df['feat_2'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('feat_2').reset_index(drop=True)

train_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)
schema = tfdv.infer_schema(statistics=train_stats)
tfdv.display_schema(schema=schema)
```

[image]

Comment: The values in the domain are correct now. However, the feat_2 is still treated as 'single' valency feature.  If I take the same initial dataframe and check for anomalies it will detect the 'AA, BB' value as missing from the schema.